# How positioned correctly divs?

Tags: css

I have 2 div.
The first div is of the form:

```
.div1 {
   display:table;
   clear:both;
}
```

The second div is of the form:

```
.div2 {
    position:absolute;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is:
How can I do 2nd div to remain after the first div considering that the first div height changes according to article.
Html must remain the same.

[image]

Comment: Don't use positioning?

Comment: after the first div means you want it out side the first div or inside the first div?

Comment: Why do you display `div1` as a table and clear it? There are no floats and this doesn't look like a tabular layout.

Comment: I want div2 to be outside

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused about the question but if you are asking what I think you are asking try adding `position: absolute;` to your div1, and adjusting the height of div 2 to being equal to the height of the webpage minus the height of div 1. You can make this a little bit easier using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables